# Player floats above platform by what looks to be 1 stud

Tags: roblox

I've been trying my hand at making games on the Roblox platform.  After making a couple of games o learn the platform, I'm working on a much larger and complicated game.  Everything seems to be going smoothly, until I noticed that the character is floating above the platform.  This is the only platform that this happens on, and it happens pretty much over the entire platform.  I'm not sure what's going on.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

[image: Character floating above platform]

EDIT: Per request, here's the properties of the platform in question.  It's a union.

[image: Platform properties part 1]

[image: Platform properties part 2]

There are no transparent parts on that platform.  In fact, the only transparent parts are on the platforms where you have to use a jump pad to get to.  Those parts are there to deflect the player onto the platform so they don't overshoot and fly off to oblivion.  Visually, the union completed, but it seems like the problem is that the surface is still there.

Comment: Are their any transparent parts where this is happening? Also could you post a picture of the properties of this part where he is hovering

Comment: @CrannMoroney Post updated with the information that you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this by creating a Union of multiple parts and then scaling them up.
[image: An image of an empty sandbox-like shape where a player stands hovering a little off the ground.]

However, if I recreated the parts and Union'd them together without scaling them afterwards, the collision geometry matched up with the actual shape.

[image: An image of a similar shape, this time, the player stands upon it without their feed hovering.]

So to fix your issue, you may need to recreate the platform to the correct size without scaling them afterwards, or without using CSG Unions.

Comment: Interesting.  However, I didn't scale it and it's having the problem.  I did some extensive research on this and found that this is a common problem when unions are used to remove elements of parts.  I also read that changing the CollisionFidelity from default to PreciseConvexDecomposition may solve the problem.  I did that and it seems to have corrected the issue.

Comment: Furthermore, the platform was made from a large block and a smaller block that was a negative part to hollow it out.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the follow up.